# Mejor opción para guardar una base de datos online con usuarios

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

me gustaría plantear el siguiente escenario para saber cuál es la mejor de las opciones para desarrollar.

Tengo una aplicación en la que acceden usuarios, cada uno con su base de datos en sql guardada internamente y ahí se almacenan sus estadísticas.

El caso es que quiero tener los datos en la nube, para poder consultarlos y tener mayor seguridad de que los usuarios no pueden modificar la base de datos para mejorar sus estadísticas de juego, ya que sospecho que es una práctica "habitual".

El usuario A no conecta con el usuario B, es una aplicación sin interactividad entre usuarios.

Ante esto, se me plantean varias cuestiones:

1. **¿Base de datos a través de Firebase o alguna página permite guardar en SQL online gratuitamente?** El volumen de usuarios tampoco es muy amplio (menos de 1000) por lo que no requiere de muchos recursos.
2. Si hago un login con registro de usuario y contraseña quizás Google me de problemas por tratar con datos de terceros, no lo sé. **¿Cuál es la mejor forma de logear?** Me gustaría que la cuenta estuviera ligada al dispositivo de modo que no 
   requiera de contraseña, pero no sé si hay alguna manera de hacerlo.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mejor de los casos es usar Firebase, yo lo utilizo ya hace 2 años y la verdad cada dia me sorprende mas, no solo por la flexibilidad con la que nos permite guardar y consultar datos, sino que todos los dias evoluciona y tiene nuevas features que cada vez le aportan mucho valor a nuestras apps !

Hay que tener en cuenta que al ser una base de datos NoSQL no vas a poder hacer consultas relacionales como estas acostumbrado. De esta forma solo habria que pensar bien la estructura de los datos antes de comenzar e ir iterando para tener una organizacion robusta para apps que escalan.

Con respecto a lo siguiente

> Quiero tener los datos en la nube, para poder consultarlos y tener
>   mayor seguridad de que los usuarios no pueden modificar la base de
>   datos para mejorar sus estadísticas de juego, ya que sospecho que es
>   una práctica "habitual".

Con Firebase , no debes de preocuparte mucho por la seguridad de tus datos ya que estan respaldados por google, y es dificil que cualquier usuario acceda a tus datos con algun exploit. Las reglas de Firebase estan muy bien hechas para que tu puedas habilitar quien escribe y lee datos. Lo unico inseguro seria solamente que te roben tu cuenta de gmail y puedan acceder a la consola de Firebase donde tienes tu proyecto, pero no deberias preocuparte si tienes algun tipo de seguridad en tu login de gmail.

> El volumen de usuarios tampoco es muy amplio (menos de 1000) por lo
>   que no requiere de muchos recursos.

Independiente al volumen de personas que tengas, lo que estas buscando es una buena UX , es decir, experiencia de usuario con tu app. No quieres tener esas 1000 o menos personas insatisfechas por usar una base de datos lerda y que no muestre los datos en el tiempo que lo solicitan los usuarios. Aca Firebase juega un papel muy importante por que al tener replicados servidores con tu informacion por todas partes del mundo, el acceso a estos datos por parte de tus usuarios es mucho mas rapido que tener un solo servidor en Estados Unidos por ejemplo. Ademas, un dato de valor, con esa cantidad de usuarios no deberias abonar casi nada con Firebase, para empezar seguro usaras el plan Free por un par de meses, si ves que no te alcanza, el plan pago por uso esta muy bien hecho ya que no llegan cifras exageradas. Yo use el plan pago por uso por un año con mas de 9000 usuarios y nunca eh pagado mas de 10 dolares al mes ! Eso si, esto tiene que ver mucho en como pides y guardas datos en Firebase, deberias optimizar todas las formas para poder hacer que las peticiones y consultas sean abreviadas. (creo que al registrarte por el plan pago por uso te acreditan 300 dolares para que uses gratuitamente)

> ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de logear?

Firebase tambien te ofrece muchas formas de loguearte, tanto Facebook, como Gmail, hasta tu propio email y contraseña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo ademas una lista de reproduccion de mi canal de youtube donde podes encontrar como crear una pantalla de login y registro con Firebase a tu eleccion.

[Creando Login con Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRU4iXC5oCw&list=PL_963TKBW5HBxL316bVJ107um9XeaZDZU&index=4)

> Me gustaría que la cuenta estuviera ligada al dispositivo de modo que
>   no requiera de contraseña, pero no sé si hay alguna manera de hacerlo.

Lo que podes hacer es usar SharedPreferences, almacenar un valor para ese dispositivo y cada vez que la app se lanza, chequeas ese valor y logueas automaticamente al usuario. Firebase ofrece lo mismo con algo que se llama AuthListener, que esuccha si el usuario ya se logueo para que no lo vuelva a hacer.

Un saludo

Comment: las preguntas que estan basadas en opiniones no se deben responder, toda vez que no tienen una unica respuesta pues depende de la experiencia de cada desarrollador entonces te sugiero no responder a preguntas de este tipo

Comment: de hecho si revisas ya tiene 2 votos para ser cerrada al basarse en opiniones

Comment: Si, disculpas por haber respondido, solo queria aportar mi experiencia y aportarle a OP herramientas sobre como lo podria hacer, un saludo